# server_names_hash_bucket_size reported on port 80 not on port 443

Tags: nginx

for my nginx conf file looking like this

```
server {
...
listen 80;
name_server www.mydomain.com;
...
}

server {
...
listen 443;
server_name phpmyadmin.mydomain.com;

}
```

I got the error message could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32

by commenting the 1st server, nginx successfully configtest the conf file. so why is it complaining against  www.mydomain.com, when phpmyadmin.mydomain.com is longer !!?

Comment: Do you have only these two `server_name` in the whole nginx config?

Comment: yes, they re the only ones configured so far. on a clean installed box. on a similar box (same distro, same version, same nginx version) it doesnt trigger any error, only the hosting provider changes.

Comment: Are there any `server_names_hash_bucket_size` or `server_names_hash_max_size` directives in your config?

Comment: I added it myself and set it to 64 to fix the problem, but I dont know why removing it , and keeping it to default (i guess 32) , didnt trigger the eror when the phpmyadmin.. domain is the only declared server (listening on 443) , however setting to listen on 80 triggers the error ... !!

Comment: It's most likely that you have more servers with `server_name` in the config listening on port 80. Check the whole configuration carefully, especially the `include` directives.

Comment: there are the only 2 mentionned above.